# MPI_Send y MPI_Recv

Tags: c, mpi

Tengo un programa paralelo de envio de mensajes utilizando la libreria mpi, pero este no funciona correctamente. Una vez mostrada la salida por consola se queda a la espera de algo y continua ejecutandose. Les muestro el codigo.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<mpi.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
int this_proc, total_procs;


MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &total_procs );
MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &this_proc );



int i;
int* localI;
localI=(int*)malloc(sizeof(double));

if(this_proc!=0){
    MPI_Send(&this_proc,1,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

}else{

     for(i=1;i<total_procs;i++){
        MPI_Recv(localI,1,MPI_INT,i,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        printf("Recibiendo mensaje del proceso nro %d \n",*localI);
     }


}
MPI_Finalize();
printf("Finalizando %d\n",this_proc);
}
```

Ejecuto en 5 procesos:

> mpirun -np 5 holaMundo

La salida por consola es la siguiente:

> ```
> Recibiendo mensaje del proceso nro 1 
> Recibiendo mensaje del proceso nro 2 
> Recibiendo mensaje del proceso nro 3 
> Recibiendo mensaje del proceso nro 4
> ```

Y el cursor queda esperando por algo. Es decir que el programa continua ejecutandose. 
No consigo darme cuenta cual es el problema. Si alguien puede ayudarme le agradecere.
Saludos. 
PD:no consegui una etiqueta mas acorde.